# citation number become disordered due to adding list of figures and tables, \usepackage{notoccite} does not work

Tags: citing, multiple-citations, notoccite

The citation number becomes disordered because of adding the list of tables and figures. The citations used in the tables and figures are numbered first. But I want the citation to be numbered from the main body.

I've tried almost every solution I could find now, which include:

(1) adding `\usepackage{notoccite}` in the preamble

(2) changing the `\caption{the figure \cite{...}}` to `\caption[the figure]{the figure \cite{...}}`

But neither of them works.

I really hope someone could help me out.

Here is my preamble part:

```
% DOCUMENT

% -> This section defines the basic thesis document. 

% Set Document Type
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  

% Select Queen's University Thesis Package
\usepackage{0_Config/1_Styles/Thesis_Style}   
    

% -> This section imports functionality which fixes Latex bugs


\usepackage{morewrites}

% SPACING

% -> This section defines the basic spacing options for the thesis document. 

\usepackage{indentfirst} % Indent first paragraph after header

% HEADINGS

\usepackage{sectsty}

% FONTS

% -> This section defines the fonts for various document entities.

\allsectionsfont{\bfseries}% set all the section font to bfseries
\chapterfont{\centering\Large} % set the sizes of chapters, sections ...
\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}

% FORMATING

% -> This section defines formatting Table of Contents entr
% example: Chapter 1 Introduction
    
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}

% for formatting Table of Contents entry for Appendix, example: Appendix 1: Stuff
\newcommand*\updatechaptername{%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\cftchappresnum{Appendix }}
}

% FOOTNOTES

% -> This section defines formating for footnotes

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 % This line stops footnotes from splitting onto two pages.

% VERBATIM

\usepackage{moreverb}        % Using this package to get better control of the
                             % verbatim environment, mostly for the use of the
                             % listing environment which puts line number
                             % beside each line.  Note that there has to be a number
                             % in each set of brackets, i.e., \begin{listing}[1]{1}.
                             % PDF info file is "The moreverb package" by
                             % Robin Fairbairns (rf@cl.cam.ac.uk) after
                             % Angus Duggan, Rainer Schopf and Victor Eijkhout, 2000/06/29.
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{verbatim}        % allows the use of \begin{comment} and \end{comment}
                             % as well as \verbatiminput{file}
                             % Note:  when using verbatim to input from a text file,
                             % such as a specification or code, use \begin{singlespacing}
                             % and \end{singlespacing}.  Also, tabs are not read
                             % properly, so the input file must only use spaces.


% GLOSSARY

% -> Creates the glossary

\usepackage[acronym,automake,toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbol}{sym}{sdn}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries

% See Glossary/Glossary.tex for the content of your glossary

% INDEX
% -> Creates the Index

\usepackage{makeidx}         
\makeindex

% MATH

% -> Import and configure packages for math
\usepackage{mathrsfs}        % For Symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}         % For More Symbols
\usepackage{amsfonts}        % For Other Symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}         % For Equations
\usepackage{amsthm}          % For Theorems & Definitions


% Using the amsthm package, define a new theorem environment for my
% definition.  * means don't number it.
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{cases}           % to make numbered cases (equations)
\usepackage{calc}            % Used with the Ventry environment defined below.

% FLOATS, PLOTS, AND FIGURES

% -> This section defines and configures packages for various styles of floating objects and figures. 
 
\usepackage{graphicx}       % for graphic images (use \includegraphics[...]{file.eps})
%\usepackage{subfigure}      % for subfigures (figures within figures)
\usepackage{subfig}         % for subfigures (figures within figures). Same as subfigures except it works.
\usepackage{wrapfig}        % for wrapping text around figures
%\usepackage{boxedminipage}  % to make boxed minipages, i.e., boxes around figures
\usepackage{rotate}         % for use of \begin{sideways} and \end{sideways}
\usepackage{listings}       % for use of printing code blocks
\usepackage{pgfplots}       % for plots
\usepackage{pdfpages}       % for importing PDFs

% Define how the ``listings'' to look.
%\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize,, numbers=left, numberstyle=\small, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, showspaces=false, lineskip=-1pt}

\usepackage{float}           % Using this package to get better control of floats
                             % including the ability to define new float types for
                             % specification and code listings.
                             % DVI info file is "An Improved Environment for Floats"
                             % by Anselm Lingnau, lingnau@tm.informatik.uni=frankfurt.de
                             % 1995/03/29.

% Style of float used for code listings
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Listing}{H}{lis}[chapter]

                             % Note:  The listings don't have space between the chapters, unlike
                             % the standard list of tables etc.  At the end, copy the spacing
                             % commands from the .toc file and insert into the .lis file.  Then,
                             % DO NOT LATEX it again, simply go to the DVI viewer!

\usepackage{placeins} % for \FloatBarrier which stops floats from crossing a point

% TABLES

% -> This section defines tables

\usepackage{tabularx}        % Package used to make variable width-columns, i.e.,
                             % column widths are changed to fit the maximum width
                             % and text is wrapped nicely.

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{lscape}         % For landscape
\usepackage{adjustbox}      % To adjust table width
\usepackage{multirow}       % For merging and splitting table cells


% CAPTIONS

% ->  This section defines captions

\usepackage{caption}   % Package used to make my captions 'hang', i.e., wrap around, but not under the name of the caption.

% MISCELLANEOUS

% ->  This section defines miscellaneous packages that facilitate miscelaneous things

\usepackage{layout}          % useful for determining the margins of a document
                             % use with \layout command
                             
\usepackage{changebar}       % Way of indicating modifications by putting bars in the
                             % margin.  Read about it in "The Latex Companion".
                             
\usepackage{enumitem}       % For enumerated lists

% REFERENCES ETC.

% ->  This section defines the reference section

\usepackage{varioref}        % Better page references, e.g., "on preceding page", etc.
                             % \vref{key} Create an enhanced reference.
                             % \vpageref[text]{key} Create an enhanced page reference.
                             % \vrefrange{key}{key} Create an enhanced range of references.
                             % \vpagerefrange[text]{key}{key} Create an enhanced range of page references.
                             % Note: doesn't really work for consecutive pages.

% Renewing the text for before and after
\renewcommand{\reftextafter}{on the next page}
\renewcommand{\reftextbefore}{on the previous page}
\usepackage{url}             % for use of \url - pretty web addresses
\usepackage{notoccite}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cite}

% Block Diagrams

% ->  This section defines imports for block diagrams and flow charts

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,arrows.meta}

% Block Diagram
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,fill=blue!20,minimum size=2em]
\def\radius{.7mm} 
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt]

% Flow Charts
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzset{
    state/.style={
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        draw=black, very thick,
        minimum height=2em,
        inner sep=2pt,
        text centered,
    },
}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,  % Change links to being coloured text, no boxes
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\circled}[1]{\lower.7ex\hbox{\tikz\draw (0pt, 0pt)%
        circle (.5em) node {\makebox[1em][c]{\small #1}};}}
    
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify what "But neither of them works" entails. E.g., after adding an optional argument to the `\caption` commands, did you re-run LaTeX twice (better still, three times) on the document? Please also tell us which bibliography style you employ.